# How do I make the same button line load different pages for my pokedex?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the pokedex exercise with JS and already have the pokemon list and made each icon into a button, now I've to make a button click call a function that will fetch the specific pokemon clicked pokeApi page to load the details of said pokemon but I don't know how to.

The button calls the loadPokePage function and it is like this for now:

```
async function loadPokePage() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.id}`)
}
```

but a can't define the pokemon.id as the specific pokemon clicked.

Comment: *"but a can't define the pokemon.id as the specific pokemon clicked"* - Why can't you?  What is `pokemon` and where is it defined?  What calls this function?  It's not clear to me what specific problem you're trying to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const detail = document.getElementById('pokemon');
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    list.innerHTML = data.results.map(res => `<li><a href="${res.url}">${res.name}</a></li>`).join('');
  })
list.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('a');
  if (!tgt) return; // not the link
  e.preventDefault(); // stop link
  fetch(e.target.href)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    //console.log(data)
    pokemon.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.sprites.front_shiny}">`
  });
});
```

```css
#container { float:left; }
```

```html
<div id="container"><ul id="list"></ul></div>
<div id="pokemon"></div>
```